# Using 'this' in Vue template inside v-for block to retrieve data dynamically based on loop variable

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I am trying to use VueJS 2 to render a simple v-for, where I would like the loop variable to represent the property I would like to access. This is a minimal example showing what I would like to achieve:

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      properties: ["a", "b", "c"],
      a: "Value Of A",
      b: "Value Of B",
      c: "Value Of C"
    };
  }
})
```

```html
 
 <div id="app">
    <div> this renders fine: a = {{ this['a'] }} </div>
    <div> 
      but this doesn't:
      <div v-for="name in properties" :key="name"> {{name}} = {{ this[name] }}</div>
    </div>
  </div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
```

Basically, I would like to render data fields selectively, and in the specific ordering dictated by the properties field. But the example cannot render anything for `{{ this[name] }}`. In fact it does not even render if I changed it to `{{ this['a'] }}` for a quick testing. `{{ this['a'] }}` if put outside the v-for block will render fine.

What could be the issue for the v-for block?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/zg9fxap4/

Comment: yes you can wrap a, b, c into another object to avoid using 'this', but I don't always have control over the model. It would be fine if I can assign this to a variable inside my template.

Comment: {{ $data[name] }} instead {{ this[name] }}

Comment: cool, and what about properties and computed properties?

Comment: Actually, you won't need call `this` in brackets, `{{ a }}` will print property `a`, either computed properties

Comment: right, but what about the v-for loop then?

Comment: Really I cant find why `this` wont work in `v-for`, so just I can suggest to call a method and return the desired result in this case

Comment: I guess a more important question is whether I should use 'this' in template? Tried Vue3 and 'this' works fine in a for loop.

Comment: For me, I used `this` in `v-on` when object key was a dynamic variable in root of data property of a component, however, you can prevent it by using computed property or method

Comment: @Mohsen do you mind putting your $data solution into an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After digging into the compiled template (via [Vue Template Explorer](https://template-explorer.vuejs.org/#%3Cdiv%20id%3D%22app%22%3E%0A%20%20%3Cdiv%20v-for%3D%22name%20in%20properties%22%20%3Akey%3D%22name%22%3E%20%7B%7Bname%7D%7D%20%3D%20%7B%7B%20this%5Bname%5D%20%7D%7D%3C%2Fdiv%3E%0A%3C%2Fdiv%3E)), I came to realize that this (simplified to just contain the problematic `v-for`) template:

```html
<div id="app">
  <div v-for="name in properties" :key="name"> {{name}} = {{ this[name] }}</div>
</div>
```

is compiled to:

```js
function render() {
  with(this) {
    return _c('div', {
      attrs: {
        "id": "app"
      }
    }, _l((properties), function (name) {
      return _c('div', {
        key: name
      }, [_v(" " + _s(name) + " = " + _s(this[name]))])
    }), 0)
  }
}
```

where `_c` is short for `createElement`, `_l` is short for `renderList`, and `_v` is short for `createTextVNode`

Now it is clear that the reason I can write `{{ a }}` without mentioning where to resolve `a` is because of the `with(this)` expression where `this` being the proxy object.

However, the problem with v-for is that the actual item renderer is passed as a callback function into `_l`:

```js
function (name) {
  return _c('div', 
            {key: name}, 
            [_v(" " + _s(name) + " = " + _s(this[name]))])
}
```

The way the callback will be called, the default binding rule applies and `this` is bound to the global window object.

With VueJS 3 ([template explorer](https://vue-next-template-explorer.netlify.app/#%7B%22src%22%3A%22%3Cdiv%20id%3D%5C%22app%5C%22%3E%5Cn%20%20%3Cdiv%20v-for%3D%5C%22name%20in%20properties%5C%22%20%3Akey%3D%5C%22name%5C%22%3E%20%7B%7Bname%7D%7D%20%3D%20%7B%7B%20this%5Bname%5D%20%7D%7D%3C%2Fdiv%3E%5Cn%3C%2Fdiv%3E%22%2C%22options%22%3A%7B%22mode%22%3A%22module%22%2C%22prefixIdentifiers%22%3Afalse%2C%22optimizeImports%22%3Afalse%2C%22hoistStatic%22%3Afalse%2C%22cacheHandlers%22%3Afalse%2C%22scopeId%22%3Anull%2C%22inline%22%3Afalse%2C%22ssrCssVars%22%3A%22%7B%20color%20%7D%22%2C%22bindingMetadata%22%3A%7B%22TestComponent%22%3A%22setup-const%22%2C%22setupRef%22%3A%22setup-ref%22%2C%22setupConst%22%3A%22setup-const%22%2C%22setupLet%22%3A%22setup-let%22%2C%22setupMaybeRef%22%3A%22setup-maybe-ref%22%2C%22setupProp%22%3A%22props%22%2C%22vMySetupDir%22%3A%22setup-const%22%7D%7D%7D)), the same template is compiled a little different:

```js
import { renderList as _renderList, Fragment as _Fragment, openBlock as _openBlock, createBlock as _createBlock, toDisplayString as _toDisplayString, createVNode as _createVNode } from "vue"

export function render(_ctx, _cache, $props, $setup, $data, $options) {
  return (_openBlock(), _createBlock("div", { id: "app" }, [
    (_openBlock(true), _createBlock(_Fragment, null, _renderList(_ctx.properties, (name) => {
      return (_openBlock(), _createBlock("div", { key: name }, _toDisplayString(name) + " = " + _toDisplayString(this[name]), 1 /* TEXT */))
    }), 128 /* KEYED_FRAGMENT */))
  ]))
}
```

Notice that the list render function is now defined as a lambda expression, hence `this` is lexically captured.

So to get the whole thing to work, I ended up with the method others suggested in comments:

```js
let app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      properties: ["a", "b", "c", "d"],

      a: "Value Of A",
      b: "Value Of B",
      c: "Value Of C"

    };
  },
  
  computed: {
    d() {
     return "Value of D";
    }
  },
    
  methods: {
    get(prop) {
        return this[prop];
    }
  },
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
   <div>
     from $data:
     <div v-for="name in properties" :key="name"> {{name}} = {{ $data[name] }}</div>
   </div>
   <div>
     from get:
     <div v-for="name in properties" :key="name"> {{name}} = {{ get(name) }}</div>
   </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Everything in a vue template has `this` automatic, by convention.  In fact, you cannot access anything other than properties, data, methods, computed, filters, etc outside of the `this` component instance in the template.

So `this` is not available because everything you declare in the template implies it.

Comment: As I understand it, you cannot really make `this` disappear in a javascript function, it is only a matter of what it refers to. I know I can directly access the fields on `this` in template without explicitly naming `this`. But I will have to know the field name statically. Here I just want to use bracket notation.

Comment: the `this` is implied in the template is the component instance.  and anything else you want to reference simply add to data or computed.

Comment: for your example create a method `get(prop)` and simply return it, using `this` in the method